# Flutter - Trying to fetch data from localhost api - get host error

Tags: php, flutter, dart

i am new to flutter. build up a test api for test app. Trying to fetch data from it and get error:

> SocketException (SocketException: OS Error: Connection refused, errno
> = 111, address = site.local, port = 49882)

OS Ubuntu 20.04,
Nginx,
php-fpm.7.3,

**Tried to use with /and without port same result. How i can fix my problem?**

```
import 'dart:async';
import 'dart:convert';
import 'posts.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;

Future<Posts> fetchPosts() async {
  Map<String, String> requestHeaders = {
       'Content-type': 'application/json',
       'Accept': 'application/json',
     };
  final response =
      await http.get('http://site.local:80/api/posts', headers: requestHeaders);

  if (response.statusCode == 200) {
    // If the server did return a 200 OK response,
    // then parse the JSON.
    return Posts.fromJson(jsonDecode(response.body));
  } else {
    // If the server did not return a 200 OK response,
    // then throw an exception.
    throw Exception('Failed to load posts');
  }
}

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  MyApp({Key key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _MyAppState createState() => _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  Future<Posts> futurePosts;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    futurePosts = fetchPosts();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Fetch Data Example',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text('Fetch Data Example'),
        ),
        body: Center(
          child: FutureBuilder<Posts>(
            future: futurePosts,
            builder: (context, snapshot) {
              if (snapshot.hasData) {
                return Text(snapshot.data.title);
              } else if (snapshot.hasError) {
                return Text("${snapshot.error}");
              }

              // By default, show a loading spinner.
              return CircularProgressIndicator();
            },
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

**Posts model**

```
class Posts {
  final int id;
  final String title;
  final String description;
  final String createdAt;
  final String updatedAt;

  Posts({this.id, this.title, this.description, this.createdAt, this.updatedAt});

  factory Posts.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    return Posts(
      id: json['id'],
      title: json['title'],
      description: json['description'],
      createdAt: json['created_at'],
      updatedAt: json['updated_at']
    );
  }
}
```

When i am doing request with `Postman` request, it return this `JSON` response:

```
[
    {
        "id": 21,
        "title": "Test 1",
        "description": "Desc test 1",
        "created_at": "2019-12-28 21:20:00",
        "updated_at": "2019-12-28 21:20:00"
    },
    {
        "id": 22,
        "title": "Test 2",
        "description": "Desc test 2",
        "created_at": "2019-12-28 21:20:00",
        "updated_at": "2019-12-28 21:20:00"
    }
]
```

Comment: Have tried using IP address instead of site.local?

Comment: @EhsanAskari how can i use ip when i have my nginx to render specific url?

Comment: @EhsanAskari I saw that solution to use ip, but it can be used in my case, because i do have a lot of projects and i use to use a hosts to work throughout nginx to work with different php projects.